# Can the audio link be different from the metadatas link?

Tags: android, streaming, shoutcast, icecast

Let's take this radio case : http://s7.voscast.com:7000

The link to stream audio from it with the MediaPlayer library of android is the same with the link giving metadatas (artist, title etc...).

1 - Is it always happening this way for icecast and shoutcast server?

2 - Could we have separate links sometimes for the 2 informations (Actual audio stream and metadatas)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking that question and a potential answer would depend on what exactly you are doing with the URLs. I suspect you are misunderstanding something. Please elaborate on what you are doing.

Comment: Basically, I am developing an android app. In the app, I am streaming audio from an audio link which is quite changing and that I am getting from the server. So far, with all the links I got for audio streaming from the server, I was able to get the metadatas from the same link. Hence my question, can it hapen sometimes to have the metadatas from a different link so that I program the app accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation I'm guessing you're scraping the HTML output of the servers for metadata. This is **WRONG**. You can not rely on it being available.

Proper metadata can be received *within* the stream. In case of an Opus or Vorbis stream it's part of the Ogg container, in case of legacy streams a HTTP header flag will enable metadata injection and you can then recover it from the stream and MUST remove it before handing it to the decoder. There might be frameworks that do all this for you.

Some initial, static, metadata is always sent as HTTP headers.

Comment: I was not scraping the HTML. As the architect of my app, I just wanted to make sure that no matter which online radio I suscribe with, the app still get the metadatas correclty (even without update). Which made me wonder what were the most common ways to pass metadatas with icecast or shoutcast. I finally found some good informations though. Thank you for your help.